# Mysql Add NULL Value in Field:

Tags: php, mysql, null

I am trying to insert a record with one field as NULL but is return an ***ERROR:Column 'paid' cannot be null***

NOTE: In Database table column *paid* is of type integer.

**CODE**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `fees_receipt_temp_table`(`id`, `voucher_no`, `std_id`, `full_name`, `payable_fee`,paid) VALUES ('','$voucher_no','$std_id','$name','$payable',NULL)";
```

Comment: It isn't the dataype. You need to check if the column 'paid' allows NULL. Share your table schema if possible

Comment: check your database structure. you probably set the column 'paid' to NOT NULL. remove the constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in your database table settings. If the column is set to be "NOT NULL", clear that constraint.

Comment: Works for me thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The database column is set on `NOT NULL`. Because of this the column does not accept NULL values.

If you wanna allow NULL as an option, you can alter it to run the following query.

```
ALTER TABLE fees_receipt_temp_table
ALTER COLUMN paid INT IS NULL
```